# Laravel: complex query using mergeBindings()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I will get the row number if the items are sorted?
This query works fine

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,pts from(
    SELECT DISTINCT             
    users.id,
    username,
    SUM(points) AS pts,
    @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,
    count(users_games.user_id) AS CountGame,
    (SELECT count(user_id) FROM users_games WHERE points=3 AND user_id=users.id ) AS win,
    (SELECT count(user_id) FROM users_games WHERE points=0 AND user_id=users.id ) AS los,
    (SELECT count(user_id) FROM users_games WHERE points=1 AND user_id=users.id ) AS draw
    FROM users_games,users 
    WHERE users_games.user_id=users.id
    AND score_home IS NOT NULL
    AND score_away IS NOT NULL 
    AND points IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY users.id
    ORDER BY pts DESC,win DESC,draw DESC,CountGame DESC
    ) t1, (SELECT @rank:=0) t2
```

but i want use it with Query Builder like this:

```
 $result= DB::table('users_games')
         ->join('users','users.id','=','users_games.user_id')
         ->select('users.id',
                  'username',
                   DB::raw('SUM(points) as pts'),
                   DB::raw('count(users_games.user_id) as CountGame'),
                   DB::raw('(select count(user_id) from users_games where points=3 and user_id=users.id) as win'),
                   DB::raw('(select count(user_id) from users_games where points=0 and user_id=users.id) as los'),
                   DB::raw('(select count(user_id) from users_games where points=1 and user_id=users.id) as draw'))
         ->whereNotNull('users_games.score_home')
         ->whereNotNull('users_games.score_away')
         ->whereNotNull('users_games.points')
         ->orderBy('pts','desc')
         ->orderBy('win','desc')
         ->orderBy('draw','desc')
         ->orderBy('CountGame','desc')
         ->groupBy('users.id');
         ->get();
```

I googled and found this function mergeBindings() and my query now looks like this but not working:

```
 $sub= DB::table('users_games')
         ->join('users','users.id','=','users_games.user_id')
         ->select('users.id',
                  'username',
                   DB::raw('SUM(points) as pts'),
                   DB::raw('count(users_games.user_id) as CountGame'),
                   DB::raw('(select count(user_id) from users_games where points=3 and user_id=users.id) as win'),
                   DB::raw('(select count(user_id) from users_games where points=0 and user_id=users.id) as los'),
                   DB::raw('(select count(user_id) from users_games where points=1 and user_id=users.id) as draw'))
         ->whereNotNull('users_games.score_home')
         ->whereNotNull('users_games.score_away')
         ->whereNotNull('users_games.points')
         ->orderBy('pts','desc')
         ->orderBy('win','desc')
         ->orderBy('draw','desc')
         ->orderBy('CountGame','desc')
         ->groupBy('users.id');

$result=DB::table( DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub") )
          ->select(DB::raw('@rank:=@rank+1 AS rank'),'pts')
          ->mergeBindings($sub->getQuery())
          ->get();
```

how i can solve this Problem?

Comment: It doesn't seem that you are taking advantage of Eloquent or Query Builder here. Isn't easier to do a `DB::raw` for the entire query?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte if i use DB:raw(my entire query)->get() not work's for me.

Comment: Use `DB::select()`, not `DB::raw()->get()`.     I don't see any bindings in your query.

Comment: Try with `\DB::select(\DB::raw('entire query'))`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte You don't need DB::raw with DB::select.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte it works but the result is a array not a collection for that i can't use this function get(),first(),paginate(10).....

Comment: @Abdessamad, you can easily convert any array to a collection with collect() in Laravel.  You'll have to implement your own pagination logic using DB::select though.

Comment: now it work's if i change last lines to:
`$result=DB::table( DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2") )->select(DB::raw('@rn:=@rn+1 AS rank'),'pts')->mergeBindings($sub)->get();`
Thanks for your help ;)